# List all subpages with custom title instead of the canonical title

Tags: mediawiki

I'm trying to show all subpages of a page. Let's say that my page looks like this (just an example, not my real data) :

```
-devices
  ↳ apple
    ↳ iPhone
    ↳ iPad
  ↳ samsung
    ↳ Galaxy
```

The title of the iPhone page is set to `iPhone: the apple phone`, the url looks like this `devices/apple/iPhone`.

How can I list, on the `devices` page all the subpages but not using the canonical title. Right now I'm using

```
{{Special:PrefixIndex/{{FULLPAGENAME}}/ |hideredirects=1 |stripprefix=1}}
```

and it returns

```
apple/iPhone
apple/iPad
samsung
samsung/galaxy
```

how can I make it returns

```
iPhone: the apple phone
apple/iPad
samsung
samsung/galaxy
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The [Display Title](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Display_Title) extension does that.

Comment: I have this extension and it works in the page but not when I’m listing the subpages